# Can I set the value for rendered attribute from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsf

Can I set the value for `rendered` attribute of `h:commandLink` from JavaScript?

```
<h:commandLink id="profileLink" rendered="#{bean.enable}">
```

Answer (score 7):

No. The `rendered` attribute is for the server side, not for the client side. In plain HTML/JS in the client cide you can just toggle the CSS `display` property.

```
// Get element by client ID.
var element = document.getElementById('formid:buttonid');

// Hide it.
element.style.display = 'none';

// Show it.
element.style.display = 'inline'; // or 'block' if it's a HTML block element
```